# Heroku and Elasticsearch - which add-on to use?

Tags: heroku, elasticsearch

I plan to use Elasticsearch on heroku.
I was looking for the best option of Elasticsearch add-on I can use.

Found was my first choice from the following reasons:

- It is now part of elastic.
- When using Elasticsearch on heroku it will be opened to the world - a secure wrapper to the transport client was introduced -  https://github.com/foundit/elasticsearch-transport-module/
  But it looks like this repository is not highly maintained, and Elasticseach 1.5 is the latest version which is supported.

What is the recommended add-on then?
 
If I want to use the latest version of Elasticsearch I am doomed to use an unsecure connection?
Maybe use the official java client?

Answer (score 2):

Nick with Bonsai here. Based on your question, and my own obvious bias, I'll suggest Bonsai for the following reasons:

- All of our clusters have SSL with basic auth to secure the connection. We feel pretty strongly that security comes as a standard feature.
- We were the first hosted Elasticsearch provider, ever. (And one of the first addon providers on Heroku, ever, with our first search addon, Websolr.) So we've got plenty of experience hosting search and and thousands of other happy Heroku customers.

One definite tradeoff with using Bonsai is that we're generally always going to lag a bit behind the latest version of ES. As of this posting we're still running ES 1.7, but updates to ES 2.2 are just around the corner.

This is probably going to be true in the future as well. Part of the reason for this is that we're a small, bootstrapped company, and we have to be pragmatic in where we focus our engineering efforts. Plus as an operations company with thousands of businesses, we like to let major new upgrades spend a few months in the wild before we commit to supporting it.

We also work hard on providing managed upgrades, at least for versions that are sufficiently backwards compatible. Everyone has their tools for helping to manage upgrades, but I don't think any of the other providers do actual in-place upgrades.

Unless you have a hard requirement for a specific feature in 2.x (and if you do, please let me know) you may do fine on 1.7 until our 2.x support is fully baked. Drop us a line at info@bonsai.io to get whitelisted for the first release of that in the coming weeks.